# Installing PHPMyAdmin on IIS 7.5 

Tags: php, iis-7.5

I am trying to install PHPMyAdmin on IIS 7.5 / Windows Server 2008 R2.

I created an application inside IIS, when I try to run the app I get an internal error,which is related to phpMyAdmin here is the log :

```
[09-Jun-2011 21:17:03] PHP Warning:  require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpMyAdmin\index.php on line 33

[09-Jun-2011 21:17:03] PHP Fatal error:  require_once() [<a href='function.require'>function.require</a>]: Failed opening required './libraries/common.inc.php' (include_path='c:\php\pear') in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpMyAdmin\index.php on line 33
```

PHP is working fine on my server!

Thank you & regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Have you verified that the files exist and the PHP has access to them?

2) Try changing the relative path to an absolute path

```
This:
require_once(./libraries/common.inc.php)

To This:
require_once(D:\Inetpub\wwwroot/libraries/common.inc.php)
/* Of course using your own path. */
```

Comment: The file doesn't exist in the libraries folder! I just extracted the downloadable phpmyadmin, did no other thing!

Comment: Is there a relation with "include_path" ? Im a newbie on PHP learning it nowadays!

Comment: Try following this: http://www.beingmanan.com/wp/2009/07/install-mysql-phpmyadmin-on-windows-for-iis/

Comment: there is something wrong, either in those posts or in the phpmyadmin that i downloaded! i can;t the files referenced in those posts!

Comment: It's a file located in the PHPmyAdmin Folder. (phpMyAdmin/libraries/common.inc.php)

Comment: for some reason, only part of the files were copied! I got it working now! thanks a lot all

Comment: No problem. Always step 1 in debugging things like this is to check if the files really exist.

Answer (score 1):

Few **possible** checks to do:

1) Please check if the required file does actually exist
`C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpMyAdmin\libraries\common.inc.php`

2) Quite unlikely, but still -- please check if that file is not currently opened by some application (your IDE or text editor may block access to that file while it opened)

3) Please check that IIS has enough access rights to read that file (it depends how your IIS is actually configured from security point of view). Members of IIS_IUSRS group should have read access (it all depends on configuration though)

You can use Process Monitor to help you figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

When installing PHP itself (I do not mean phpMyAdmin) you must expand (+) the various install options. Pear is not a default install. Like in Microsoft apps doing a custom install where you select all of the features to be installed on the hard drive.